# Why isn't my tkinter initialisation giving an output?

Tags: python, tkinter, replit

```
import tkinter as tk    

class Display:

  #sets up initial window and its settings    
  def __init__(self):    
    self.root = tk.Tk()    
    self.root.title("Quote Finder")
    self.root.geometry("300x300")
    self.root.resizable(False, False)
    self.root.configure(bg = "white")

  #creates the frames that are going to be used in the program
  def frames(self):
    self.search_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.root, bg = "white")
    self.search_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

    self.quote_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.root, bg = "white", padx = 10, pady = 10)
    self.quote_frame.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

  #creates the widgets used to generate/find quotes
  def heading(self, random, search):
    self.title = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Quote Finder", bg = "white")
    self.title.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

    self.search_bar = tk.Entry(self.search_frame)
    self.search_bar.grid(row = 0, column = 0, ipadx = 30)
    self.search_bar.insert(0, "enter a tag that describes the quote")

    self.search_button = tk.Button(self.search_frame, text = "Search", command = lambda: search)
    self.search_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    self.empty_row1 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "", bg = "white")
    self.empty_row1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

    self.random_button = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Generate Random Quote", command = lambda: random)
    self.random_button.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "w", columnspan = 3)

    self.empty_row2 = tk.Label(self.root, text = "", bg = "white")
    self.empty_row2.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

  #creates the widget for displaying the quotes and scrolling through them
  def quote_display(self, next, back):
    self.quote_label = tk.Label(self.quote_frame, text = "Quote", bg = "white")
    self.quote_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    self.next_button = tk.Button(self.root, text = ">", command = next)
    self.next_button.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = "e")

    self.back_button = tk.Button(self.root, text = "<", command = back)
    self.back_button.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = "w")


display = Display()
```

I'm trying to test the `__init__` function of the class but it outputs nothing, anyone know why?

I have tested running the same program in different files but it still won't work.
BTW I'm coding on repl.it so I'm not sure if it's just an issue with their app.

Comment: You code only calls the `__init__` method in `Display` and nothing else. You never run the other methods that you defined. Therefore, you can only expect to get a blank white non-resizable window that is 300x300 pixels in size and with a title. Try adding `self.frames()`/`self.heading()`/`self.quote_display()` in your `__init__`method to actually run those methods.

Comment: "I'm trying to test the init function of the class but it outputs nothing, anyone know why?" - I'm not sure I understand. What do you think it should "output", and why do you think it should do so?

Answer (score 0):

Hi add the following at the end of your file
root is your handle to your window object.
That's why you need to access it via the root variable so I would suggest that chaning the root variable into window.

```
display = Display()
display.root.pack_propagate()
display.root.mainloop()
```

Setting it as public and the rest as private would be ideal using leading underscore.
Or a better solution might be applying inheritance rule's on the Display class.